# How to monitor all nodes works well?

Tags: ros, node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are some nodes work together ,I want to monitor all nodes . Avoid one or some of these nodes are broken or died,how to write a script or something to reach this goal ? Does ros have any  mechanisms or solutions？

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/259584/how-to-monitor-all-nodes-works-well-?/) by [Tomas yuan](https://answers.ros.org/users/29377/tomas-yuan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2017-04-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Then you need to use a bond, which allows  processes, to know when the others have terminated, either cleanly or by crashing.

the official doc is here: http://wiki.ros.org/bond

---

Originally posted by [ΦXocę 웃 Пepeúpa ツ](https://answers.ros.org/users/29728/%CF%86xoc%C4%99-%EC%9B%83-%D0%BFepe%C3%BApa-%E3%83%84/) with karma: 424 on 2017-04-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tomas yuan](https://answers.ros.org/users/29377/tomas-yuan/) on 2017-04-19**:
Thank you,I will have a try

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If your nodes themselves do not need to know about the status of other nodes, but you just want to make sure that if one node dies then the whole system stops, then `roslaunch` will do what you want. For each node in your launch file, set the `required` attribute (see http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/node#Attributes) to true. Then, if any of your nodes die, `roslaunch` will kill all the others and stop your system.

---

Originally posted by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) with karma: 4203 on 2017-04-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not sure if this is exactly what you are after but you could try using a watchdog (http://wiki.ros.org/watchdog_timer).

---

Originally posted by [msadowski](https://answers.ros.org/users/19897/msadowski/) with karma: 311 on 2017-04-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1